# Variable inside a function not changing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup

In my validate function, I am trying to find if there is an error.
My bool variable changes inside yup's reach method but when the method is done, the variable returns to default value. Here is my code:

```
validatePerson= () => {
   let errorHappened=false;
   yup.reach(yupSchema, 'Person.name').validate(this.state.Person.name).catch(error => 
        {
            errorHappened=true;
            console.log(errorHappened) //true
        });
   console.log(errorHappened) //false
}
```

I tried to use `var` but the result was same. Any ideas?
Edit:In console, the output order is like this:

```
false
true
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `yup`, but are you sure that code is running synchronously?

Comment: @DBS reach.catch() seems to return(?) promise object so it seems like its async function

Answer (score 0):

`errorHappened` is changed in a callback, The callback means it is not executed immediately, it is executed later. So `console.log(errorHappened)` out of the callback is executed first.